# Someone explain the venn diagram for the logic equation A*(B+C)

Tags: logic, circuits

So, I am studying logic circuits and how to prove them with Venn diagrams. When drawing a Venn diagram for the equation A*(B+C) I figured it would look something like this:
[image]

But according to the answer key, and wolfram alpha, it looks something like this:
[image]

Can someone explain why this is? Because doesn't A*(B+C) simplify to A*B + A*C, which would only be the two shaded regions?

Comment: Honestly, I've _never_ seen Venn diagrams used for this.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Yes you have! They are drawn rectangular and called Karnaugh diagrams :)

Comment: @HendrikJan Smiley noted but the following is only a minor paraphrase. David: "I've _never_ seen truth tables drawn this way." Hendrik: "You have, but they were drawn a different way." David: "Well, they weren't drawn _this_ way then, were they?" In particular, a Karnaugh map doesn't represent the set of states where a particular variable is true as a contiguous region, so it's not a Venn diagram in any way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're absolutely right that $A\times(B+C) = AB+AC$. This means that the formula is true whenever one *or both* of the following hold:

- $A$ is true and $B$ is true;
- $A$ is true and $C$ is true.

Note that the first case doesn't say anything about the value of $C$ – it could be true or false.  Similarly, the second case doesn't require anything about $B$. If $A$, $B$ and $C$ are all true, we're in both cases, so the formula is true.

Answer (score 3):

$(B+C) = B\overline{C}+\overline{B}C + BC$

and A with that and you get:

$A*(B+C) = A*(B\overline{C}+\overline{B}C + BC) = AB\overline{C}+A\overline{B}C + ABC$

Remember that OR is the *union* and AND is the *intersection*.